# Display live chart on Figma

Tags: python, user-interface, android-livedata, figma

Can we display live data in form of the chart on Figma? I have a python code that extracts live data of the stock market. Initially, I thought of using Tkinter to create a GUI, but due to its ugly interface, I decided to shift to Figma.

is there any way that I can connect Figma to my python code in order to generate a live graph on Figma? My python program provides data in form of a Pandas Dataframe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot share live ongoing data and display it through *Figma*
because *Figma* is a graphics editor  and prototyping tool.
You can input your live data but its a one time process, if you input it will display on the prototype and you cant refresh it and see new real time data...here are some plugins that might help you

1. [Google Sheet sync](https://www.figma.com/blog/plugins-to-help-you-design-with-real-content/#google-sheets-sync)
2. [Unsplash](https://www.figma.com/blog/plugins-to-help-you-design-with-real-content/#unsplash)
3. [Data Lab](https://www.figma.com/blog/plugins-to-help-you-design-with-real-content/#data-lab)
4. [Content Reel](https://www.figma.com/blog/plugins-to-help-you-design-with-real-content/#content-reel)

I hope that this will help you and you got the answer.